# How to determine the list of files over which to expand in the middle of the workflow?

Tags: parameters, snakemake

At some point my snakemake workflow creates a file ovlp.txt, of which I do not know upfront how many lines it will contain. I then wish to split up this file into smaller files of 25000 lines, which are all called ovlp_split{s}.txt. For this I have the rule split (see below). Next, each of these files will be processed using the rule predict (see below), which has as input all files ovlp_split{s}.txt. Finally all files are processed together in the rule merge_predict below. As you can see, several times I need to expand the list of input or output files over all splits. However, since I do not know the size of the file ovlp.txt until it is created by an earlier rule, I do not know how many splits there will be. How can I resolve this?

I hope this was sufficiently clear, please let me know if there are parts that are not.

Thanks!

Marleen

```
rule split:
    input:
        'ovlp.txt'
    output:
        expand('ovlp_split{s}.txt', s=splits)
    run:
        shell('split -l '+str(lines_per_file)+' -a 4 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt ovlp.txt ovlp_split')

rule predict:
    input:
        'ovlp_split{s}.txt',
    output:
        'ovlp_predict_split{s}.txt',
    run:
        (command that processes the file)

rule merge_predict:
    input:
        expand('ovlp_predict_split{s}.txt', s=splits)
    output:
        'ovlp_merged.txt'
    run:
        (command that processed the separate files and creates one final output file)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to use [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution). Maybe along these lines:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'ovlp_merged.txt',

checkpoint split:
    input:
        'ovlp.txt'
    output:
        splitd= directory('ovlp_split'),
    shell:
        r"""
        mkdir {output.splitd}
        split -l 3 -a 4 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt ovlp.txt {output.splitd}/
        """

rule predict:
    input:
        'ovlp_split/{s}.txt',
    output:
        'ovlp_predict_split{s}.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        cp {input} {output}
        """

def aggregate_split(wildcards):
    chkp_done = checkpoints.split.get().output.splitd
    chkp_output = sorted(glob_wildcards(os.path.join(chkp_done, "{s}.txt")).s)
    return expand('ovlp_predict_split{s}.txt', s= chkp_output)

rule merge_predict:
    input:
        aggregate_split,
    output:
        'ovlp_merged.txt'
    shell:
        r"""
        cat {input} > {output}
        """
```